# HSV range for open cv iOS

Tags: ios, opencv

I am trying to detect skin in iOS through open cv. My Code is mentioned below.

```
cvCvtColor(&srcIplImage, &hsvIplImage, CV_BGR2HSV);

CvScalar lower = cvScalar(0, 58, 88);
CvScalar upper = cvScalar(25, 173, 229);

cvInRangeS(&hsvIplImage, lower, upper, &srcGrayIplImage);

cvCvtColor(&srcGrayIplImage, &dstIplImage, CV_GRAY2BGR);
```

In android, it works perfectly and detects skin properly. But in iOS I get very unexpected result. I think there are different ranges of HSV being used by open cv in iOS and Android. For android my lower and upper limits are ok, but the same is not for iOS.

If anyone as faced this kind of problem, please help me out for the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How to detect WHITE color using openCV HSV scalar values ? Eg- In the link mentioned below red color is detected using HSV values range - solarianprogrammer.com/2015/05/08/… . It would be great if someone could provide me the lower and upper values exactly in same format. For ref other links : colorizer.org , stackoverflow.com/questions/10948589/

Answer (score 3):

I have sorted out the issue by hit and trial. Normal HSV range is as mentioned below.

Hue: 0 - 360. (Its' an angle)
Saturation: 0 - 100 (Intensity of color)
Value: 0 - 100 (Brightness)

in iOS it has the following range,
Hue: 0 - 180. (Its' an angle)
Saturation: 0 - 255 (Intensity of color)
Value: 0 - 255 (Brightness)

in Android

Hue: 0 - 360. (Its' an angle)
Saturation: 0 - 255 (Intensity of color)
Value: 0 - 255 (Brightness)

Another you need to take care that the color scheme in iOS OpenCV is BGR not RGB. So the Hue section will cover Blue color in range of 0-60 degree instead of red. You will have to change the Hue value accordingly for iOS.

Hope this can be useful to someone else :)

Comment: At my best knowledge when using colorWithHue the ranges appear to be colorWithHue: 0.0 - 1.0 saturation: 0.0 - 1.0 brightness: 0.0 - 1.0 alpha; 0.0 - 1.0. Anything below 0.0 casts to 0.0, anything above 1.0 casts to 1.0. I'm using iOS 10.3.2, Xcode 8.3.3 Hardware: Mac mini with macOS 10.12.5, iPad mini A1489.